# Remove object from a list of objects

Tags: reactjs, object, jsx, create-react-app

I have a object of objects (`{0: {name: "foo", price: "2.32unit"}, 1: {name: "bar", price: "0.45unit"}}` etc...)

I have tried many thing shuch as

- `JSON.stringify(o)` and then removing the text, but that screwd up the indexes.
- Converting to an array and `delete a.indexOf(name)`

and some more I can't remember.

The question is: how can I remove an object with only the name given from said list (`{0: {name: "foo", price: "2.32unit"}, 1: {name: "bar", price: "0.45unit"}}` etc...) and how do i find an object's index by it's name?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `delete` to remove entry from object

```js
let obj = {
    0: {name: '0'},
    1: {name: '1'},
    2: {name: '2'}
}


delete obj[1];

console.log(obj);
```